# C# Убить процесс по местоположению

Tags: c#

Открыто несколько Portable версий Google Chrome одновременно.

У всех процесс `chrome.exe`, но убить нужно определённый Chrome.

Как это сделать? Есть идея как-то отделить их по местоположению на `.exe`, но не знаю как реализовать.

Comment: если открыто несколько инстансов портабл, то по логике у всех них будет одно и то же местоположение

Comment: Это разные `.exe` из разных папок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если у тебя есть все нужные процессы собраны проверить путь можно по

```
string fullPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
```